# How can I compare filename without getting permission denied message in bash?

Tags: bash, command-line

I want to look through all files in my directory and subdirectory
then delete files with special name

Here is my code

```
for filename in $1*;do
    if("$filename" == "hello.txt");then
            echo "WOW!"
    fi
    done
```

My test directory is TEST/ and there are two files. one name "hello.txt" and "world.txt";However, when I run the code I receive

```
noStrange.sh: line 2: TEST/hello.txt: Permission denied
noStrange.sh: line 2: TEST/world.txt: Permission denied
```

I tried the command `chmod u+x scriptname`, it doesn't work

This is what I input

```
sh scriptname TEST/
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `basename` command to get the basename of a file from file path variable.

```
for filename in $1*;do if [[ $(basename "$filename") == "hello.txt" ]] ; then echo "wow";fi;    done
```

Or

Use find command. This would search through all the files exists in the current folder as well it's sub folders.

```
find . -name 'hello.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

The immediate answer is that your syntax for tests is wrong; you should have

`if ["$filename" == "hello.txt"]; then`

etc.  However, there are a few issues with your code.  Since `$filename` will match `TEST/hello.txt` instead of `hello.txt`, you probably won't get the behavior you want.  Also, if you're looking to just delete files with certain names, you probably want a normal UNIX command like

`rm TEST/hello.txt`

If there are patterns you want do delete, you can use glob/wildcards, or a combination of `find`, `xargs` and `rm`.  E.g.

`find TEST -name 'hello*.txt' | xargs rm`

Comment: You need spaces around the brackets in your test expression. Also, `==` is a nonstandard bashism, in `[ ]` it's better to use just `=`.